# How can I show a JDialog at the start of my main JFrame form?

Tags: java, netbeans

**Good evening,**

I have a simple Java application I'm working on.  I've gotten stuck and I need some assistance.  This is a project we were working on in my Java Programming class.

I've created a JFrame form and several JDialog forms that I calling successfully using buttons located on the JFrame form.  For one of the JDialog forms (**dlg_create_company**), I'd like that to popup immediately as a modal window when the application starts.  So far I've tried calling the code from the main method of the JFrame form, but I run into the "can't call a non-static variable in a static context" error.

**Here's what I'm trying:**

```
    //Create a new instance of my JDialog "dlg_create_company" and assign it to "dialog"
    //Then set it's visibility to true.
    dlg_create_company dialog = new dlg_create_company(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true, current_company);
    dialog.my_parent = this; //sets form frm_repair_shop as the parent via the my_parent reference.
    dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  [**Here's a link**](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55174425/repair_shop_WK5.zip) to a zip of my entire project.

Comment: How does the `current_company` field get populated?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Have a look at my answer. If it is not correct, which I think has a high probability of, I will delete it. Expert critique please ;-)

Comment: @LittleChild I don't think it's incorrect, the question lacks context.  Does the OP want the frame visible before or after the dialog? Where does the information for the dialog come from?  Calling a dialog from within a constructor (IMHO) isn't the greatest of ideas, but that's just (and yes, I've done it to :P)). That's just me ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer If not in the constructor then where ? :)

Comment: @LittleChild That's a design choice. Personally, I would probably construct the frame, make it visible and display the dialog separately after it. The problem is, the dialog is relying on information from the frame, for which I have no context for...

Comment: Thanks guys, you're all right.  I didn't show how current_company was being populated because I didn't think it was necessary.  Perhaps a novice mistake, please forgive me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, you cannot access a static variable in non-static context. That is because static variables 'exist all the time' while non static objects may or may not 'exist'. You need to show the dialog box in the constructor of your `JFrame` and make both of them visible. The `JFrame` first and the `JDialog` after.

And please, post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) instead of linking to the ZIP file. Maybe tomorrow people will start linking to their Github asking us to debug it.

```
public MyJFrame(){
    // add components
    // call pack and stuff
    // instantiate the JDialog
    // make JFrame visible
    // make the JDialog visible
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, this worked for me.  Please accept my apologies, I didn't know anything about SSCCE until tonight.  I have taken it into advisement and will not repeat this mistake.  Thanks again.